# Missing results when using the SE cross-site search

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, google, search

I often notice that when I use the [SE cross-site search engine](https://stackexchange.com/search) (which is powered by Google), I get just a small subset of the results obtained by searching Google with the operator: `site:stackexchange.com`.

In many cases the additional results found by Google are meaningful appearances of the search term, which are not duplicates of the appearances found by the SE engine.
Here are a few examples for the number of search results obtained by each method, at the time of writing of this question:

```
╔══════════════════╦════╦════════╗
║   Search term    ║ SE ║ Google ║
╠══════════════════╬════╬════════╣
║ football manager ║  6 ║   1120 ║
║ roomba           ║  3 ║   1490 ║
║ papercut         ║  8 ║    180 ║
║ treehouse        ║  2 ║    552 ║
╚══════════════════╩════╩════════╝
```

**Is there a good reason for this discrepancy?

Is this a bug?**

Comment: Well, one possible reason is that the custom site search we build (with Google) excludes per site metas. It is a list of just the main site urls as well, nothing else, no blogs, etc. So site:stackexchange.com is pretty broad considering all the stuff that is under that domain.

Comment: That's a possible reason, but it doesn't account for all the missing results. [Here is one example](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/10367/5083) of a question about a treehouse, which is a question on a main site and not a site meta, but which doesn't appear in the search results of the SE engine. A quick scan of the search results for the terms in the above table will reveal many such examples.

Comment: Sure, that's fair, just pointing out some obvious differences.